# Fabric digits doesn't send confirmation code once the phone number has been used

Tags: twitter-fabric, twitter-digits

if it's a new phone number, everything works fine, however if I repeat the login again with previous phone number, then no confirmation code is sent over even if i change to another phone or even change the app bundle, is anybody else having such problem?

we're trying to integrate the "find friends" feature provided by Twitter Fabric, it seems Fabric Digits is the only solution, is there any other existing service available? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

App developers require debugging their apps and for that repeating sign in process for success/ failure multiple times is mendatory. Fabric Digits by Twitter has done a very good job in providing at least 30-40 sign ins attempts (successful/ failure) for the same number before stopping sending more confirmation codes for that number **`for that day`**. Yes, as per my experience, Digits blocks (if at all) for that day only. Next day, you can again start requesting OTPs for the same number.

I know at least 5-6 developers who have successfully implemented Digits into their production app and the above observation held true for all of them.

The good news is you can always write to Digits Support Team which responds very quickly. I hope this information helped you

Comment: Mike from Crashlytics and Fabric here. One other thing to note is that there is now a Sandbox version of Digits that's available (though it's in beta). More info here on Android: https://docs.fabric.io/android/digits/sandbox.html and on iOS: https://docs.fabric.io/apple/digits/sandbox.html